# How to solve first order complex differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, complex, code-request, code-generation

I want to solve these differential equations and want to get the value of 'a1'. I used this code given below but it is not showing any result.
If anyone can resolve this will be appreciated.

```
wm = 1;
G1 = 0.005;
delc = 1;
ka = 0.1;
E0 = 0.4;
gma1 = 0.5;
g0 = 1;
kd = 0.2;
del0 = 1;
N1 = 1;
NDSolve[{q1'[t] - wm*p1[t] == 0, 
 p1'[t] + wm*q1[t] - G1*Abs[a1[t]]^2 + gma1*p1[t] == 0, 
 a1'[t] + (I*delc + ka)*a1[t] - I*G1*a1[t]*q1[t] - E0 + I*g0*s1[t] == 
 0, s1'[t] + (kd - I*del0/2*N1)*s1[t] - I*g0*a1[t]*N1 == 0, 
q1[0] == 0, p1[0] == 0, a1[0] == 1, s1[0] == 0}, {q1, p1, a1, 
s1}, {t, 0, 100}]
Show[a1[t]]
```

here 'Abs' is used for, dagger of a[t] multiply with a[t].

Comment: Have you looked at the error messages? `NDSolve::underdet "There are more dependent variables, {a1[t],p1[t],q[t],q1[t],s1[t]}, \
than equations, so the system is underdetermined"`

Comment: @Nasser Many have solved these types of equations numerically. Should I separate these equations in the imaginary and real terms and then after solve?

Comment: Possibly, yes, but first, I would worry about having more dependent variables than equations than worry about the complex part. Is having more dependent variables than equations intentional?

Comment: One of your DE's has the varible `q[t]`.  Maybe it should be `q1[t]` ?

Comment: @LouisB yes you are right. Now I need the value of 'a1'. how can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to plot the real and imaginary parts of the solution for `a1[t` is like this

```
soln = NDSolve[{q1'[t] - wm*p1[t] == 0,
    p1'[t] + wm*q1[t] - G1*Abs[a1[t]]^2 + gma1*p1[t] == 0, 
    a1'[t] + (I*delc + ka)*a1[t] - I*G1*a1[t]*q1[t] - E0 + 
      I*g0*s1[t] == 0, 
    s1'[t] + (kd - I*del0/2*N1)*s1[t] - I*g0*a1[t]*N1 == 0,
    q1[0] == 0, p1[0] == 0, a1[0] == 1, s1[0] == 0}, {q1, p1, a1, 
    s1}, {t, 0, 100}];

ReImPlot[a1[t] /. soln, {t, 0, 15}]
```

[image]

To create a similar plot with Mathematica 9 we can code

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Re@a1[t], Im@a1[t]} /. soln], {t, 0, 15},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

The latest Mathematica features, however, are available with a basic Wolfram Cloud account (free).

Comment: Thankyou. It is helpful.

Comment: But I am using Mathematica version 9.0 . The plot is not shown.